# HTML JQuery Displaying Date

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been trying to display the time by doing this.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title>My Schedule</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var now = new Date();
        $("#foot").append(now.toLocaleTimeString());
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<header>Day.</header>
<ul type="disc">
    <li>Monday</li>
    <ol type="circle">
    <li>Breakfast</li>
    <li>Lunch</li>
    <li>Dinner</li>
</ol>
<li>Tuesday</li>
<ul type="circle">
    <li>Lunch</li>
    <li>Dinner</li>
</ul>
</ul>
<footer id=”foot”>Current Time:</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

and then displayed with

`<footer id=”foot”>`

but I can't get it to work, can someone tell me if this is viable and how it could be fixed?

Thanks for the time and help.

Comment: Can you post the HTML you are using as well?

Comment: works fine here  http://jsfiddle.net/69qzf/1

Comment: Just make sure your HTML reads `<footer id="foot"></footer>` and you mark your HTML with `<!doctype html>` to properly make it an HTML5 document so browsers can see the `footer` tag.

Comment: Change your quotes from ”  to " or '

Comment: I tried posting the entire HTML but even with the code indentation it would not display the HTML tags, can you explain how I would do it?

Comment: If you wish to post the entire HTML, you should put it in "code" tags (select it and click the code icon). You say you did this already... make sure you use the code button and don't just indent. Otherwise I don't know, try posting to http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @miro  quote style is irrelevant so long as they match

Comment: My mistake, misused JSFiddle.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pK5K5/ - JSFiddle of his exact code. Not sure what's wrong?

Comment: @ChristianStewart in the jsfiddle the qoutes around `foot` in the html are wrong type. delete and put in `"` and the fiddle works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only problem with the code in this question are the weird `quotes` around the id `foot`. change them and the code works:

[**jsFIDDLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/aaaheatair/pK5K5/1/)